# How to use Gatsby with TypeScript and Netlify functions

Tags: typescript, babeljs, gatsby, serverless, netlify

I set up Gatsby with Netlify functions using [this tutorial](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/gatsby/using-netlify-functions-with-gatsby/#using-functions),
and everything works as expected, except that I would love to use TypeScript for the serverless functions code.

The Gatsby build command transpiles the frontend typescript to javascript, so I guess that I need a custom build script to transpile the typescript serverless function code, with 'node' as a target.
How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this Serverless plugin ([serverless-plugin-typescript](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-typescript)). Once installed by:

```
yarn add --dev serverless-plugin-typescript typescript
# or
npm install -D serverless-plugin-typescript typescript
```

You'll need to configure your `serverless.yml`:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
```

You only last to add your TypeScript custom configuration in the `tsconfig.json`, for example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "rootDir": "./"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I asked about ceased to exist: [Netlify Functions now support TypeScript](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/04/19/announcing-native-typescript-support-for-netlify-functions/)